# Why is it not standard to implement abstraction layers for the file system?

Tags: unit-testing, abstraction, file-systems

I have been taught to access databases through abstraction layers. I was wondering why it is not also standard practice to access the file system through an abstraction layer? It seems to me unit testing would become much simpler, since mocking the filesystem is often a pain and poorly supported by some languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the vast majority of languages and frameworks, the **stream** is an abstract concept, and methods can be designed to accept generic streams (which can be substituted for in-memory data) instead of concrete file system objects.

I personally have not found much benefit to unit-testing file operations beyond that level, because there are so many things that can go wrong in practice that the unit tests prove almost nothing at all about the application's ability to perform its function.

It's actually a lot like database abstractions; typically you don't try to abstract something like the database connection or an ORM session/context/whatever, you just create a "repository" or "query" abstraction to encapsulate all the data access and mock that. So file I/O isn't that much different; you don't generally want to abstract the file system itself, just the *operation* being performed on the file system expressed in terms of the problem domain, and that needs to be done in user code.

If you're finding that you need to mock the file system, I'd say your system-under-test is getting a little too intimate with it. Just delegate those file operations to a handful of higher-level abstractions and exclude their implementations from code coverage, like you would normally do with SQL queries.

Comment: +1 I wrap the file system for unit testing, but I don't try to abstract it.

Comment: +1 I believe what you were trying to say is "Presume the FS works and shouldn't be tested. Then, if you have a class that ReadsSomething(), implement it in terms of the interface GetSomething(), which this specific implementation of it just so happens to actually read from a file, which, as we said, is presumably working behavior."

Answer (score -1):

The abstraction seems pragmatically little too heavy for very little we usually we do with fileSystems.

You can do it but when you weigh it against the volume of stuff we do(which i think is minimal) and the value it provides by abstraction.. IMO a little too much for so little